# Отправка письма на node js nodemailer

Tags: node.js, reactjs

На node js использую express.

````
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const PORT = 3001
const mailer = require('./mailer')

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.use('/static/css',express.static(__dirname + '/static/css'))
app.use('/static/js',express.static(__dirname + '/static/js'))
app.use('/static/media',express.static(__dirname + '/static/media'))
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname + '/'))

let user = undefined
app.post('/api/email',(req,res)=> {
    const {email,subject,message,title,phone,mailing} = req.body
    const msg = {
        from:'info@winfields.law',
        to:'info@winfields.law',
        subject:subject,
        html:
            `
            <h1 style="color: #3f4259">Имя пользователя :${subject}</h1>
            <h4 style="padding: 10px;background-color: #50526e;color: #fff;">Тема сообщения: ${title}</h4>
            <p style="padding: 10px;background-color: #f8f9fa;color: #50526e;">Текст сообщения: ${message}</p>
            <i>Телефон пользователя: ${phone}</i>
            <div style="color: var(--bs-gray); font-size: 12px; margin-top: 20px">Этот пользователь на рассылку ${mailing}</div>
            `
    }

    mailer(msg)
    user = req.body
    res.redirect('/')
})

app.get('/api/email',(req, res) => {
    if(typeof user !== 'object') {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
    } else {
        res.send('Вы успешно отправили почту')
        user = undefined
    }
})


app.listen(PORT,() => {
    console.log(`server started in: http://localhost:${PORT}/`)
})```

Создал файл где экспортирую mailer

    ```const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host:'smtp.mail.ru',
    port:465,
    secure:true,
    auth: {
        user:'***',
        pass:'***'
    }
})

const mailer = message => {
    transporter.sendMail(message,(err,info) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err)
        console.log('Email send: ' + info)
    })
}

    module.exports = mailer ```


Локально письма отправляются, а вот после скачивания приложения на хост, письма не отправляются
Помогите плз
````

Comment: Дополните ваш вопрос, указав какие ошибки возникают и где именно.

Comment: начиная с 30 мая 2022 года Google больше не поддерживает сторонние приложения и устройства, которые предлагают войти в аккаунт Google только с помощью имени пользователя и пароля

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй этот код, у меня все работало на Heroku

```
var app = require('express')();
let cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening web server');
});

//Подключение модулей для отправки на почту
require('dotenv').config()
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.PASSWORD
    }
})

// Функция отправка данных на почту
function sendemail(email,text) 
{
    const mailOptions ={
        from: 'coachkurswork@gmail.com',
        to: email ,
        subject: 'Заявка на сайте',
        text: text
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо, но мне нужно на почту на mail.ru отправить письмо. Оно где то теряется, не доходит на почту.